# python, pandas, calculate several means with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, mean

My question: I have the following array and I want to determine the mean of count1, count2 and count3 with respect to each word. I guess I have to use the "groupby" method but I don't understand how it works to calculate more than one mean.

```
     word  count1 count2 count3
0    a        30      10      8
1    the      20      12      0
2    a        60      15     14
3    an       5       13      8
4    the      10      4       5
```

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: Rather than asking two questions in one, please instead ask two separate questions.

Comment: Answer to question 1 have a read of [missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html), for second question explore [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I did it. But I still can't understand the groupby doc :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use `df.groupby('word').mean()`.  The groupby method tells Pandas to make groups of of the data by looking at the column 'word'.  We then aggregate the data by taking the mean. (There are plenty of other options available, such as sum, min, max.)

`word      count1   count2   count3
a            45     12.5     11.0
an            5     13.0      8.0
the          15      8.0      2.5`

To understand it more generally, try running groupby on a simple example data frame to see what you can do with it, and read the documentation on the links in the comments above.

Comment: But I don't understand how to form the array you are showing with the Serie df.groupby('word').mean(). Is there an natural way to rebuild it as a well shaped DataFrame?

Comment: Save it `df2 = df.groupby('word').mean()` then reset the index `df2 = df2.reset_index`